# Why delegate object is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates

I am facing little weird issue with delegate pattern and I couldn't make it work like I expect. I guess I am missing something here but I couldn't figure it out myself.

Here's how my classes are defined,

```
class NetworkManager {

    weak var delegate: DownloaderProtocol?

    func downloadFile(downloadUrl: URL ) {
        downloadTask(with: downloadUrl).resume()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        delegate?.downloadCompleted(task: task, error: error)
    }
}


class DownloadManager: DownloaderProtocol {

    var networkManager: NetworkManager

    init(networkManager: NetworkManager) {
        self.networkManager = networkManager
    }

    func downloadMatches(urls: [String]) {
        self.networkManager.delegate = self

        for(....) {
            self.networkManager.downloadFile(url: url)
        }
    }

    func downloadCompleted(task: URLSessionTask, error: Error) {
        // Implementation
    }
}



class Matches {

    var networkManager: NetworkManager
    init() {
        self.networkManager = NetworkManager()
    }

    func getMatchSchedules(urls: [String] , completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
        return DownloadManager.downloadMatches(urls: [String])
    }
}
```

**What is the issue ?**

When the urlSession - didCompleteWithError method is called, I can see that delegate object is **nil**.

**What I have tried ?**

1. If I remove the weak reference of the delegate i.e `weak var delegate: DownloaderProtocol?` to `var delegate: DownloaderProtocol?`, then the delegate object is not nil. It works fine.
2. I even tried to set the delegates in Matches class, but the delegate is still shown as nil

Any help or point out is welcome.

Comment: Your code is unclear. But I'd tend to say that your object might be released too son (scope issue?). The line `return DownloadManager.downloadMatches(urls: [String])` is strange (static func, but not declared as such, there is no return, etc.)

Comment: @Larme, sorry I am using a completion handlers

Comment: Other variables in network manager doesn't seem to have this issue, only delegate is nil. Surprisingly I just saw the delegate working  ONLY in debug mode (with breakpoints)

Comment: noob question where do you assign the delegate of network manager since matches instance there is not a reference to delegate, I don't see where you set networkManager.delegate = DownloadManager()

Comment: @kjoe. Perhaps you should look into the Download manager class where I am setting the delegate

Comment: yeah I saw in there is a class that conform to the protocol, but not seen a instance of that class set to the delegate in networkManger.as soon as you create the first instance of networkManager you need to inject the delegate or create an instance of the delegate and set to it.

Comment: @kjoe. Gotcha. Network manager object is passed from Matches class and the delegate is set in the Download manager class.

Comment: yeah but then you have a retain cycle there, you have to create the delegate object in maches and inject there or set there, and your Download Manager does not hace a networkManger property

Comment: @kjoe, updated the question about the instances you were saying

Comment: "If I remove the weak reference of the delegate i.e weak var delegate: DownloaderProtocol? to var delegate: DownloaderProtocol?, then the delegate object is not nil" OK, so what this implies is that the delegate you are assigning has no independent existence. Your `delegate` variable is the only thing retaining it. That's fine but then this is not a delegate; it is some sort of decorating helper. A delegate is an object that already exists elsewhere.

Comment: Also note that your code makes no sense. You cannot say `DownloadManager.downloadMatches` because `downloadMatches` is an _instance_ property.

Comment: Thanks matt. I guess your first comment makes me to think of how I am using a delegate here. DownloadManager.downloadMatches is used so that every time DownloadManager obj is created (Different objects for each download - for now)

Answer (score 0):

well I recommend this approach since is not all you code that posted in the question but just the relevant one.

```
 class NetworkManager {

    weak var delegate: DownloaderProtocol?

    func downloadFile(downloadUrl: URL ) {
        downloadTask(with: downloadUrl).resume()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        delegate?.downloadCompleted(task: task, error: error)
    }
}


class DownloadManager: DownloaderProtocol {

    var networkManager: NetworkManager

    init(networkManager: NetworkManager) {
        self.networkManager = networkManager
        self.networkManager.delegate = self
    }

    func downloadMatches(urls: [String]) {


        for url in urls {
            guard let url = URL(string: url) else {return}
            self.networkManager.downloadFile(downloadUrl: url)
        }
    }

    func downloadCompleted(task: URLSessionTask, error: Error) {
        // Implementation
    }
}



class Matches {

    var downloadManager: DownloadManager//NetworkManager
    init() {
        //self.networkManager = NetworkManager()
        //self.networkManager.delegate = DownloadManager()
        let networkManager = NetworkManager()
        self.downloadManager = DownloadManager(networkManager: networkManager)
    }

    func getMatchSchedules(urls: [String] , completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
        return downloadManager.downloadMatches(urls: ["asadsdad"])
    }
}
```

you need a download manager in matches that have a network manager when you create  matches you create the network manger and set to the init of the download manager so you have a delegate set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback in place of delegate.
It's much easier approach than delegate.

```
typealias APIServiceSuccessCallback = ((Any?) -> ())
```

ViewController A:

```
//call from A -> B result fire if completionHandler fire in VC B
    addCompanyTargetsController.responseCreateBookingObj = { [unowned self] (returnObject) in
                    if let object = returnObject as? [String:Any] {
                        if object["success"] as? Bool == true {
                            self.loadTargetList()//success block
                        }
                    }
                }
```

ViewController B:

```
var responseCreateBookingObj : APIServiceSuccessCallback? //declaration

func completionHandler() { //from where you fire call this method
        guard let callBack = self.responseCreateBookingObj else{
            return
        }
        callBack( true as AnyObject)
    }
```